# Email with special characters to Tumblr

Tags: php, email, tumblr

I'm using a PHP script to email a posting to Tumblr and Posterous. For Posterous special characters are showing up in the posting but for Tumblr it don't. 
(In general Tumblr does support special character - I tried it out with emailing from Gmail) 
So what could be the problem?

Here my PHP header:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
           ."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$bound_text\"\r\n";

$message =  "--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"
           ."Content-Type: multipart/related; type=\"text/html\"; boundary=PHP-mixed2-$bound_text\r\n\r\n"
           ."--PHP-mixed2-$bound_text\r\n"
           ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
           ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
```

I already tried several charsets and Content-Transfer-Encoding combinations without any different result.

Any ideas are welcome.
Michael

Comment: Have you tryed sending yourself an email from Gmail and then inspecting the headers?

Comment: Don't build your own mime messages. Use Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org) or PHPMailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com) do it for you. Far more reliable and easier to use than rolling your own.

Comment: What special characters are you trying to send?

Comment: @Arvin These special characters: ßÄÖùâêîôûëÿæœÙÂÊÎ - Any idea welcome what to try. @Manhim What should I do then with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into how my GMail account sent it and found out it used `windows-1252` for the charset and the text is base64 encoded (this may not be case in using other GMail accounts). The email I sent below was successfully posted by tumblr and I used the function [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) to generate the correct base64 string.

```
$data = wordwrap(base64_encode(utf8_decode($stringWithSpecialCharacters)));
```

The raw email message is below:

```
To: myuploademail@tumblr.com
Subject: tumblr post from sudocode
from: omime class <script@sudocode.net>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary=omime_1308940625_c0d4e36fd504619028804e8b23ceb12a


--omime_1308940625_c0d4e36fd504619028804e8b23ceb12a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

38TW+eLq7vT76//mP9nCys4=
--omime_1308940625_c0d4e36fd504619028804e8b23ceb12a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

38TW+eLq7vT76//mP9nCys4=
--omime_1308940625_c0d4e36fd504619028804e8b23ceb12a--
```

I used my [omime class](http://sudocode.net/sources/includes/class-omime-php/) to send the email and here's the code I used:

```
$email = new omime('alternative');
$email->attachText('ßÄÖùâêîôûëÿæœÙÂÊÎ');
$email->attachHTML('ßÄÖùâêîôûëÿæœÙÂÊÎ');

$email->send('mysecretuploademail@tumblr.com', 'test tumblr post', 'from: omime class <script@sudocode.net>');
```

Comment: "I looked into how GMail sends it and found out it uses windows-1252 for the charset" -- gmail probably just respects whatever charset your client uses.  On non-windows OSes, it's probably not gonna be windows-1252.  At first glance, email composed on my ubuntu desktop seems to be UTF-8.

Comment: @Frank I'm not implying that it should be sent that way to make it work. I'm just giving an example of a case that worked for me. The raw email I included in my answer is the one I generated from my own code. Sure, I'll rephrase what I said.